# How do you add dynamic 'where' clauses to a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I've got a User table with a bitmask that contains the user's roles. The linq query below returns all the users whose roles include 1, 4 or 16.

```
var users = from u in dc.Users
            where ((u.UserRolesBitmask & 1) == 1)
               || ((u.UserRolesBitmask & 4) == 4)
               || ((u.UserRolesBitmask & 16) == 16)
            select u;
```

I'd like to rewrite this into the method below to returns all the users from the given roles so I can reuse it:

```
private List<User> GetUsersFromRoles(uint[] UserRoles) {}
```

Any pointers on how to dynamically build my query? Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) class.

PredicateBuilder has been released in the [LINQKit NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/)

> LINQKit is a free set of extensions for LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework power users.

Comment: Apparantly the PredicateBuilder class is available in two versions: the source code example on the website, which is © Albahari & O'Reilly, all rights reserved; and as part of LinqKit, which is "under a permissive free license, which means you can modify it as you please, and incorporate it into your own commercial or non-commercial software."

Comment: LinqKit is available via NuGet.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your UserRoles values are themselves bitmasks, would something like this work?

```
private List<User> GetUsersFromRoles(uint[] UserRoles) {
    uint roleMask = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < UserRoles.Length;i++) roleMask= roleMask| UserRoles[i];
    // roleMasknow contains the OR'ed bitfields of the roles we're looking for

    return (from u in dc.Users where (u.UserRolesBitmask & roleMask) > 0) select u);
}
```

There's probably a nice LINQ syntax that'll work in place of the loops, but the concept should be the same.

Comment: This should work. Instead of dynamic where clause you reduced it to a single one. And that nice LINQ syntax you mentioned could be:
uint roleMask = UserRoles.Aggregate(0,
          (combined, role) => combined | role);

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

LINQ Dynamic query libraries:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Expression Trees & Lamda expressions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way of adding a variable number of *where* clauses to your LINQ query.
Note that I haven't touched your bitmask logic, I just focused on the multiple *where*s.

```
// C#
private List<User> GetUsersFromRoles(uint[] UserRoles)
{
   var users = dc.Users;

   foreach (uint role in UserRoles)
   {
      users = users.Where(u => (u.UserRolesBitmask & role) == role);
   }

   return users.ToList();
}
```

---

EDIT: Actually, this will **AND** the *where* clauses and you wanted to **OR** them. The following approach (a inner join) works in LINQ to Objects but can not be translated to SQL with LINQ to SQL:

```
var result = from user in Users
             from role in UserRoles
             where (user.UserRolesBitmask & role) == role
             select user;
```

Answer (score 1):

How's this? It is not dynamic linq, but accomplishes the goal.

```
private List<User> GetUsersFromRoles(uint[] userRoles) 
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    foreach(uint userRole in UserRoles)
    {
        List<User> usersInRole = GetUsersFromRole(userRole);
        foreach(User user in usersInRole )
        {
            users.Add(user);
        }
    }
    return users;
}    

private List<User> GetUsersFromRole(uint userRole) 
{
    var users = from u in dc.Users
            where ((u.UserRolesBitmask & UserRole) == UserRole)
            select u;

    return users;    
}
```

Comment: Also, you need to ToList in GetUsersFromRole

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<User> GetUsersFromRoles(uint UserRoles) {
  return from u in dc.Users            
         where (u.UserRolesBitmask & UserRoles) != 0
         select u;
}
```

UserRoles parameter should be provided, however, as a bit mask, instead of array.

Comment: This will return the users who match ALL the given roles. His method return users who match ANY of the given roles.