# How do I build up dynamic linq queries to solve a set of constraints?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, constraints

I'm looking for a way to build up linq querys for a special problem.

Given is a set of variables like x1, x2, x3...., which can take an integral number and a set of expressions like x1>=5, x2>=7, Math.Sqrt(x1+x2)=8....containing some of the variables.

My intention is to get a solution for the variables which takes the expressions into account.

For a given example, you can create something like this:

```
    var zeroToMaxValue = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue); 
    var cp = zeroToMaxValue.AsParallel()
        .Where(x1 => x1 >= 5)
        .Select(x1 => new { x1 });
    var cp2=cp
        .SelectMany(query => zeroToMaxValue,(query, x2) => new { query.x1, x2 })
        .Where(query => query.x2 >= 7 && Math.Sqrt(query.x2 + query.x1) == 8);
    var result = cp2.First();
    {
        Console.WriteLine("x1: " + result.x1 + " x2: " + result.x2);
    }
```

Output is: x1:5 x2: 59

Does anyone know how do create this kind of querys dynamically
so that I get a solution where each expression is fulfilled.

I've already tried the PredicateBuilder class and searched the posts about the subject, like [How do you add dynamic 'where' clauses to a linq query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180405/how-do-you-add-dynamic-where-clauses-to-a-linq-query). But nothing I've tried worked.

One of my main problems is the fact, that I have to select many variables, each of them with its own set of numbers. Is it right that this implies, that I have to build up as many queries as there are variables, each using the query before as basis, like in the example above?

Last thing I could do is building these kind of queries with a stringbuilder, but I hope someone can help me and knows a better way.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Take a look at [LINQ TO Z3 – THEOREM SOLVING ON STEROIDS](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/09/27/linq-to-z3-theorem-solving-on-steroids-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = //.....

foreach (var constraint in constraints)
{
  query = query.Where(constraint);
}
```

Comment: This would build up one query. Due to the fact that I have more than one variable and each variable is represented by a set of numbers (e.g. IEnumerable<int> zeroToMaxValue), I have to build the cross product of all these sets where this one query works with.

Comment: I could build the cross product like this (e.g.):
            var query = from x1 in zeroToMaxValue
                        from x2 in zeroToMaxValue
                        select new{x1, x2};
But I don't know how to continue. The type of the constraints is not yet fix, i could transform it into a string or in something else (possibly). Of which type must my constraints be to work on the datastructure given by the crossproduct {x1:int, x2: int}?