# Using linq to filter a search

Tags: c#, database, linq, search, filter

I am trying to use Linq to query a database from a search user control.

I have this Linq query that searches the database with a user's input.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
var query = from invite in db.invites
            where invite.Division == userInput.Division.Text &&
                  invite.Status == userInput.Status.Text
            select invite;
```

The problem I have is that if either one is empty I need to not take it into account for the search filter.  Is there a way to do this properly, taking in consideration that I have many filters and not just status and division?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add dynamic 'where' clauses to a linq query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180405/how-do-you-add-dynamic-where-clauses-to-a-linq-query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to deferred execution you can conditionally build the query in pieces.

```
var query = db.invites.AsQueryable();

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput.Division.Text))
    query = query.Where(invite => invite.Division == userInput.Division.Text);

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput.Status.Text))
    query = query.Where(invite => invite.Status== userInput.Status.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var query = from invite in db.invites
        where invite.Division.Matches(userInput.Division.Text) &&
              invite.Status.Matches(userInput.Status.Text)
        select invite;
```

---

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static bool Matches(this string text, string value)
    {
      if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return true;
      return text == value; // or same safer comparison
    }
}
```

there are better ways to build queries, but this is simple (and `Matches` needs a better name).

As @willem notes, I missed the point of query being executed on the database which seems likely (`db.invites`) - however, I am leaving the answer here as it works for Linq to Objects queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from invite in db.invites
        where invite.Division.Contains(userInput.Division.Text) &&
              invite.Status.Contains(userInput.Status.Text)
        select invite;
```

or

```
var query = from invite in db.invites select invite;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput.Division.Text)) query = query.Where(invite => invite.Division == userInput.Division.Text);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput.Division.Text)) query = query.Where(invite => invite.Status == userInput.Status.Text);
```

Comment: first example doesn't behave in the same way as original

Comment: Your right, though something about his question tells me that he might be looking exactly for that solution.

Comment: I cannot comment on your post ( !@%@#$^@#$^@#$^ ) but isn't your solution going to say that the sql server doesn't reconize your function, because it is code that that only runs inside the application and not on the SQL server?

Comment: I haven't even considered the possibility that this is related to SQL :) You are probably right, but the answer is correct for any Linq to Objects query. I will edit it.

Comment: Am using Linq to Sql. I might have forgotten to specify this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some extensions, I've built a library to make this a little more readable. https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqConditionalExtensions

```
var hasDivision = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput.Division.Text);
var hasStatus = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput.Status.Text);

var query = db.Invites
    .WhereIf(hasDivision, invite => invite.Division == userInput.Division.Text)
    .WhereIf(hasStatus, invite => invite.Status == userInput.Status.Text);
```

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/xKloc/LinqConditionalExtensions